# Segmentation fault when pushing on stack (NASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm, fault

I'm trying to get a nasm program running.
The following code:

```
segment .data

contAir:    dt 1.11330e-10
constOil:   dt 2.33656e-10

segment .text

global calc

calc:

mov edx, 0
push ebp
;mov ebp, esp

;mov eax, [ebp + 8]

ret
```

I get a segmentation fault (core dump) when pushing ebp on the stack. Why is that?
I'm running this code on an Ubuntu virtual machine.
Funny thing is, sometimes I get an "illegal instruction" error.

Comment: Are you compiling it on the machine too?

Comment: Yes. It is a C-program that uses some assembler code. But the C-code runs fine as far as my output shows me.

Comment: Can you please add all the sources to your question?

Comment: Technically, `ret` is not the proper way to exit your program and return back to the OS.  You need to use `exit` or `int 80`, but since you said a C program, are you calling this?  If so, you need to `pop  ebp` before your `ret`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I get a segmentation fault (core dump) when pushing ebp on the stack. Why is that? I'm running this code on an Ubuntu virtual machine. Funny thing is, sometimes I get an "illegal instruction" error.

I'd bet that you're not getting the segmentation fault at the `push`, but rather at the `ret`. What the `ret` instruction does is pop the return address from the stack (which typically will have been pushed there by a `call` instruction) and jumps to it.

So when you do this:

```
push ebp
ret
```

You're effectively jumping to whatever address happened to be stored in `ebp`.
You need to balance the stack before returning - i.e. each push-type instruction should have a corresponding pop-type instruction:

```
push ebp
; ... other code goes here ...
pop ebp
ret
```