# nasm , 64 ,linux, segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

this is foo.asm

```
extern choose;
[section .data]
num1st dq 3
num2nd dq 4
[section .text]
global main
global myprint
main:
  push qword [num2nd]
  push qword [num1st]
  call choose
  add esp,8
  mov ebx,0
  mov eax,1
  int 0x80
  ;  pop qword [num1st]
  ;  pop qword [num2nd]
myprint:
  mov edx,[esp+8]
  mov ecx,[esp+4]
  mov ebx,1
  mov eax,4
  int 0x80
  ;  pop qword [num1st]
  ;  pop qword [num2nd]
  ret
```

it is a  C-asm-program

this is bar.c

```
void myprint(char * msg ,int len);
int choose(int a,int b) 
{ 
  if (a>=b){
    myprint("the 1st one\n",13);}
  else {
    myprint("the 2nd one\n",13);}
  return 0;
}
```

nasm -f elf64 foo.asm

gcc -c bar.c

gcc -s -o foobar bar.o foo.o

./foobar ，it says segmentation fault core dumped

I use gdb to debug ,but it says missing debuginfo-install, I am also trying to install it.

maybe the problem has sth to do with the 86_64 arch...

[Segmentation fault when pushing on stack (NASM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174150/segmentation-fault-when-pushing-on-stack-nasm)
after watched this link,I add some 'pop' into it but it doesn't work

Comment: Your functions don't seem to obey any sensible calling conventions?!  They also don't seem to set up the stack frame.

Comment: what is in myprint(..)?

Comment: thank you for reading !!! I'm sorry I will edit it !!!! I miss the way to compile the two!!!

Comment: myprint() is in the C-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are not passed on the stack [in 64-bit mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), unless you have more than 6 of them. The first two arguments will be in `RDI` and `RSI`.

There's also a difference in how you should use system calls in 64-bit mode. The syscall number and arguments should be placed in the following registers ([source](http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/post/2011/07/05/Linux-syscall-ABI)):

```
syscall nr  rax
arg 1       rdi
arg 2       rsi
arg 3       rdx
arg 4       r10
arg 5       r9
arg 6       r8
```

And the `sys_write` syscall number in 64-bit mode [is 1, not 4](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64). Also, instead of `int 0x80` [you should use `syscall`](http://callumscode.com/blog/3). Performing syscalls with `int 0x80` *might* work in 64-bit mode depending on how your kernel has been configured, but you still need to consider how function arguments are passed.

Comment: by the way,how to let the cpu arch don't affect my program (not my code)?

Comment: If you program in assembly you will be affected by the CPU architecture. It comes with the territory. I suggest that you avoid using system calls directly unless you have a very good reason to do so, and instead use libc functions like `puts` and `printf`. That will at least solve part of the problem.